# Add decorator from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have a decorator like this:

```py
def foo(func):
    """Will print the args and kwargs of a func"""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Do I have args?')
        print(args, kwargs, sep='\n')

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

And a 'decorator maker' like this:

```py
def add_checks(*decorators):
    """Adds decorators to a func"""
    def check(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # how do I add here the `*decorators`?
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return check
```

How do I add decorators by the string? So it's something like this:

```py
@add_checks('foo')
def bar(a, b, c=1):
    return (a * b) / c

print(bar(5, 2, c=5))
>>> Do I have args?
>>> [5, 2]
>>> {'c': 5}
>>> 2
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to string-index your decorators rather than just use the function references inline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to iterate over `*decorators`:

```
import functools


def foo(func):
    """Will print the args and kwargs of a func"""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Do I have args?')
        print(args, kwargs, sep='\n')
        #return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


def add_checks(*decorators):
    """Adds decorators to a func"""
    def check(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for dec in decorators:
                if isinstance(dec, str):
                    # lookup for the function in globals()
                    globals()[dec](func)(*args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    dec(func)(*args, **kwargs)

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return check


@add_checks(foo)  # reference to the function!
def bar(a, b, c=1):
    return (a * b) / c


@add_checks("foo")
def bar_strDecorated(a, b, c=1):
    return (a * b) / c


print(bar(5, 2, c=5))
print(bar_strDecorated(5, 2, c=5))
```

Out:

```
Do I have args?
(5, 2)
{'c': 5}
2.0
Do I have args?
(5, 2)
{'c': 5}
2.0
```

Comment: Good solution, although shouldn't the wrapped functions sit within each other, rather than just be called one after the other? i.e. the first decorator should be able to mutate the arguments/kwargs passed to the next one, and so on.

I appreciate that the OP didn't let us in on the grand plan for this system, so I'm left speculating!

Comment: Man the `globals` key lookup just looks weird, would `eval` actually be a better fit here? I like the solution otherwise

Comment: Personally I hate the idea of exploring for code using globals or otherwise. Using function references (as Maurice said) is the right way forward. But if you're going to do that, why use this pattern at all? Just stack the decorators.